# Revoked token and authentication cookies

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

We are using idsrv3 at work and here are my setup and the problematic scenario:

we use idserv with reference tokens, implicit flow, 1 web api and 1 angularjs client.

Our client doesn't want a user logged multiple times on the website.

1. the user A connects to site on chrome
2. the user A connects to site on firefox and the token of A on chrome is revoked.
3. api returns 401 to user A on chrome, revoked worked
4. chrome redirects user to signin page with oidc-client (signinredirect)
5. user is automatically logged in, because the authentication cookies are still valid.

We also have a silent renew for the access token.

Now I want to force the kicked out user to re-authenticate but it's impossible to do without deleting the authentication cookies.

How can I achieve that?

I have considered to have a very long access token (stored in session store) and ephemere authentication cookies, or
to delete the cookies just before the signin redirect which will jinx the silent renew.

what is my best option?

thank you.

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to make this possible. But I think in this case you've reached a point where you should ask yourself whether you should fix this. It seems to me that user A should make up his mind and choose one browser. Why is user A using two different browsers simultaneously? Are you really willing to possibly downgrade your security for this non-issue?

Comment: Hi Ruard, thanks for you comment. It's also to prevent users to use the same credentials on different computers at the same time. Would it be possible in this case? And the issue is non negotiable right now...